# queryexpression where with concatenate columns

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

i want to create Xrm QueryExpression with concatenate two column in where clause and need to search like SQL as below:

```
      select * from contact where forename+' '+surname like '%yo%'
```

My QueryExpression is below:

```
QueryExpression pagequery = new QueryExpression();
        pagequery.EntityName = "contact";
        pagequery.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("firstname" + "lastname", ConditionOperator.Equal, "yo"));
        pagequery.ColumnSet.AddColumns("firstname", "fullname", "emailaddress1", "lastname");
EntityCollection results = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(pagequery);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like what you are practically trying to achieve is locating "yo" within either the first or last name. Why not just do an _OR_ condition? `firstname contains "yo" OR lastname contains "yo"`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible in a way you mentioned. What I can suggest is following:

1. Add calculated field of string type and make it populated with sum of your 2 fields.
2. Build your query using field that you have created.